# Public key creation in AWS cloudformation giving following error: Invalid request provided: AWS::CloudFront::PublicKey

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I have the following Cloudformation template (.yml file) where I am creating Public key to add to a Keygroup, also created in same template. (The public key below is just for example purpose.)

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources:
  CloudfrontPublicKey:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::PublicKey
    Properties:
      PublicKeyConfig:
        CallerReference: 'some-caller-reference'
        Comment: 'Public key for signed url'
        Name: 'cloudfront-public-key'
        EncodedKey: '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----aaaabbbb-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'
  CloudFrontKeyGroup:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::KeyGroup
    Properties:
      KeyGroupConfig:
        Comment: 'Key group for signed url'
        Items:
          - !Ref CloudfrontPublicKey
        Name: 'cloudfront-key-group'
```

However, I am getting the following error relating to the public key

```
  Invalid request provided: AWS::CloudFront::PublicKey
```

The original public key is multi-line, for example:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
aaaa
bbbb
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I tried to make it fit in single line by adding new line character as follows

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\naaaa\nbbbb\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I also tried without the new line character

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----aaaabbbb-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Both attempts did not work, and I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, you can use **multi-line strings** in yaml for that kind of situations. Thus you may try the following version of the template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources:
  CloudfrontPublicKey:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::PublicKey
    Properties:
      PublicKeyConfig:
        CallerReference: 'some-caller-reference'
        Comment: 'Public key for signed url'
        Name: 'cloudfront-public-key'
        EncodedKey: |
          -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
          aaaa
          bbbb
          -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

  CloudFrontKeyGroup:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::KeyGroup
    Properties:
      KeyGroupConfig:
        Comment: 'Key group for signed url'
        Items:
          - !Ref CloudfrontPublicKey
        Name: 'cloudfront-key-group'
```

Comment: The error related to PubicKey vanished after I tried your solution. Another solution was to use double quotes to wrap the  one liner public key with \n.

Answer (score 1):

You might also get the same error if you *try* to update an `AWS::CloudFront::PublicKey` resource. These resources are immutable. If you want to change the `Name`, `EncodedKey`, or `CallerReference` values, you have to create a new PublicKey and add it to the KeyGroup.  (Or delete the `CloudfrontPublicKey` in your example above, deploy, recreate the `CloudfrontPublicKey`, and deploy again.)

I've documented more in a blog post: [You’re getting "Invalid request provided: AWS::CloudFront::PublicKey" because CloudFront Public Keys are immutable](https://dltj.org/article/cloudformation-invalid-request-cloudfront-publickey/).

Answer (score 0):

I found success in this same situation using an approach suggested by [samtoddler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2246345/samtoddler) [in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66397831/1505423) on another very similar question:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"

Parameters:
  PublicKey:
    Default: "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\naaaa\nbbbb\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----" # note the encoded line breaks

Resources:
  CloudfrontPublicKey:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::PublicKey
    Properties:
      PublicKeyConfig:
        CallerReference: 'some-caller-reference'
        Comment: 'Public key for signed url'
        Name: 'cloudfront-public-key'
        EncodedKey: !Sub "${PublicKey}" # this is the magic trick
```

TL;DR - pass the public key in (with its line breaks encoded as `\n`) to the template as a parameter, which you reference for `EncodedKey` using `!Sub` and wrapping the param with double quotes. I hope this helps!