# How to pass public key from parameter file in cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I have defined the following a Cloudformation template, where I want to pass Public Key from a parameter file. The 'MyPublicKey' variable is of string type. I refer to this variable by using

```
EncodedKey !Ref MyPublicKey
```

under PublicKeyConfig as seen below.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"

  Parameters:
    MyPublicKey:
      Type: String
      Description: 'Public key for some purpose'
      NoEcho: true

  Resources:
    CloudfrontPublicKey:
      Type: AWS::CloudFront::PublicKey
      Properties:
        PublicKeyConfig:
          CallerReference: 'some-caller-reference'
          Comment: 'Public key for signed url'
          Name: 'cloudfront-public-key'
          EncodedKey: !Ref MyPublicKey

    ...
```

The parameter.json file looks something like this. The public key was multi line in the original .pem file but I have added new lines character '\n' in the string whereever there is a line break.

```
[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "MyPublicKey",
    "ParameterValue": "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\naaaa\nbbbb\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
  },
]
```

When trying to update the stack, I get the following error:

```
Invalid request provided: AWS::CloudFront::PublicKey
```

It does not seem to be able to import the public key.

Comment: I think there should be one more `\n` char in the encoded key at the end as per this [create-public-key](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudfront/create-public-key.html#create-public-key). Just a hunch.

Comment: @samtoddler It did not work.

Comment: just the encoding is missing, take a close on the example doc I attached, I am not sure how your key looks like, and how you have generated it. If it is via the CLI it is already encoded.

Comment: I used these commands to generate the key: 'openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 2048' and ''openssl rsa -pubout -in private_key.pem -out public_key.pem".

Comment: Your key should look like this `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAy/a9J+kUsH97bcrAZ7AR\nw/eT/RB9pxGyCWNZpllUqjAxBCqemfoXAH/3SEW+9GjRHOTCDHP8Ds1VUDmh2vZn\nm3SOUHdcWZkCAjhPxmuiU9rhcd3Ti1A9fNv9S8rM+GAA2ElLmHOoXbNHulWqvJO6\nwym57g1uZds3StmHQgWKWvOi792PAgjZUKjx0CD3AyL2ILTjXascuuzaI7bIAiqV\nup7J/3scpbTJpd17hLTzFVjYk/QX20v62s0LS+M/LSKf9yg22ezJzOTaoQA738hI\n1QphXi3LZAcp1uiJNIas6emtaSgBgFp+vHOLJmQQTSADMExzcodnxshBX1h+Ljoy\nSQIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n`. As you can see there are mulitple newline char in this key.

Comment: This is the temp key I generated using the commands you shared. If you dont want to do it manually you can simply add them manually via the console and get use [get-public-key](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudfront/get-public-key.html#get-public-key) via the CLI, it will give the encoded key.

Comment: I uploaded the key in AWS and used get-public-key to get the value of the key from CLI, and pasted it in parameter file. Still not working.

Comment: added the full working example.

Comment: It is now solved. So, I added the extra '\n' at the end as you suggested and replaced 'EncodedKey: !Ref MyPublicKey' with 'EncodedKey: !Sub "${PublicKey}"

Comment: glad it worked out!!

Comment: can you mark this as resolved?, I added the explanation below in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on comments an extra `\n` char was needed when passing the value and `Ref` should be replaced with `Sub` function for placing the string.

```yaml
  Resources:
    CloudfrontPublicKey:
      Type: AWS::CloudFront::PublicKey
      Properties:
        PublicKeyConfig:
          CallerReference: 'some-caller-reference'
          Comment: 'Public key for signed url'
          Name: 'cloudfront-public-key'
          EncodedKey: !Sub "${MyPublicKey}"
```

Below is the inline key example:

Generate keys:

```sh
openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 2048
openssl rsa -pubout -in private_key.pem -out public_key.pem
```

Cloudformationt template:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources:
  CloudfrontPublicKey:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::PublicKey
    Properties:
      PublicKeyConfig:
        CallerReference: 'some-caller-reference'
        Comment: 'Public key for signed url'
        Name: 'cloudfront-public-key'
        EncodedKey: |
          -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
          MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsG0grTw5uHbO4CkFVyqN
          lKLGd9ZJrj6l68QU20SzrF7jgQtzE7VKfHxWfzE5FDKF1qKVLT0mURjlRfRPUXaT
          sZYsnKv+cTYkraewdLqbVuN7JII2D/cEXTYRn7849kGKycl3YMXeJeBStbLSPWfh
          MNJZnlFnEX6DkYtwk0Ae0bQ3WT1Be/Xhe4pqSQsnU+InSDkIfA+4UTRLa0kTCgON
          8BjcNloJE3NbLYshQPconb8pA+3jjkMF0QAH6rtc452G7CuS3KBfVQwWUeWE77kK
          wQQir6YFvKP3pG8Ls55FxXBTCCNJl5LZcHt1D0cZmuoSLJj2mVzJgKGyLTdoIwAW
          6QIDAQAB
          -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Listing keys:

```sh
aws cloudfront list-public-keys|jq .PublicKeyList.Items[1]
```

Output:

```json
{
  "Id": "08ZCTRKADSADASDAS",
  "Name": "cloudfront-public-key",
  "CreatedTime": "2021-02-27T10:25:43.076Z",
  "EncodedKey": "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsG0grTw5uHbO4CkFVyqN\nlKLGd9ZJrj6l68QU20SzrF7jgQtzE7VKfHxWfzE5FDKF1qKVLT0mURjlRfRPUXaT\nsZYsnKv+cTYkraewdLqbVuN7JII2D/cEXTYRn7849kGKycl3YMXeJeBStbLSPWfh\nMNJZnlFnEX6DkYtwk0Ae0bQ3WT1Be/Xhe4pqSQsnU+InSDkIfA+4UTRLa0kTCgON\n8BjcNloJE3NbLYscZmuoSLJj2mVzJgKGyLTdoIwAW\n6QIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n",
  "Comment": "Public key for signed url"
}
```

[Public key creation in AWS cloudformation giving following error: Invalid request provided: AWS::CloudFront::PublicKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66348050/public-key-creation-in-aws-cloudformation-giving-following-error-invalid-reques) already answered.

Comment: Had to change 'EncodedKey: !Ref MyPublicKey' with  'EncodedKey: !Sub "${PublicKey} "